# What is the best jQuery based window plug-in you have ever used?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I tried a couple of jQuery based window plug-ins but unfortunately was not satisfied with any of them. Here's what I tried:

- http://hernan.amiune.com/labs/jQuery-Windows-Engine-Plugin/jQuery-Windows-Engine-Plugin.html
- http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/
- http://www.soyos.net/aerowindow-jquery.html

I need following features without any compromises:

- Maximize, minimize (to a reasonable location such as bottom-left corner of the visible page, not in the middle of the screen), drag, resize, etc.
- Highly and easily configurable
- Actively developed (this can be relaxed a little bit)
- Comes with good documentation (and examples)
- works cross-browser (I had problems in IE when I tried to use fstoke.me's implementation).

The three plug-ins I have tried failed in one or more respects. I'm not looking for very fancy, animated effects, just very basic but yet adequate functionality.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Good luck with that IE requirement.

Comment: i think you'll love this: This plugin is a modified copy of
jQuery UI Dialog widget, adding
minimize, restore and maximize buttons
 http://carvalhar.com/componente/jQueryDialogr/index.html

Comment: aSeptik, jQuery Dialogr fails in IE 8 (minimize does not work as expected).

Comment: i think is something trivial you can fix it as easy! ;)

Comment: The more I look at them the more I think Jimmy's comment is a wise one... :(

Answer (score 2):

I know it's kind of late to reply, but still. I am developing a plugin based on Hernán's jQuery Windows Engine. You can check it out [here](https://bitbucket.org/mingos/jquery-windows-engine).

Answer (score 1):

I developed the first you mentioned http://hernan.amiune.com/labs/jQuery-Windows-Engine-Plugin/jQuery-Windows-Engine-Plugin.html and after a year receiving suggestions to improve it and to add functionality I have refactored the code to provide more flexibility to developers.

Let me know if you know if there is something that I can improve.

Answer (score 1):

@MRR:

I'm pretty familiar with the problem you are having.

The escape key feature is not part of that jquery plugin, it is in another file and just closes all the opened windows spawned by the jquery window engine plugin.

In my opinion, you should check the zindex of each window and start closing the one with the highest zindex first, then on the next escape the next one etc etc.. until you have no windows left :)

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem you meet when you try to use fstoke.me's implementation in IE? :)

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I have with Jquery Windows Engine is that when I press escape it closes all the windows at once instead of closing the select/most recent window open. Do you think its possible to have control over what the ESC button does as I cannot find anything tangible in the JS file